# TemplateView serialize some context data to json

Tags: json, django, serialization, django-class-based-views

I've found many related question, but with no luck =(

**views**

```
from django.core import serializers

class LargeMapView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'map/index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LargeMapView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        human_values = Human.objects.all()
        search_work_values = SearchWork.objects.all()

        # context['human_data'] = json.dumps(list(human_values))
        # context['search_work_data'] = json.dumps(list(search_work_values), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)

        context['human_data'] = serializers.serialize('json', human_values)
        context['search_work_data'] = serializers.serialize('json', search_work_values)

    return context
```

**template**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       var lala = {{ human_data }};
</script>
```

In result I have `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &` :

```
 var lala = [{&quot;pk&quot;: 13, &quot;model&quot;: &quot;human.human&quot;, &quot;fields&quot;: {&quot;burial_type&quot;: null, &quot;last_name&quot;: &quot;&quot;, ...
```

Comment: Try `var lala = JSON.parse({{ human_data|escapejs }})`?

Comment: @mariodev `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL ` `JSON.parse([{\u0022pk\u0022: 13, \u0022model\u0022: \u0022human.human\u0022, \u0022fields\u0022: {\u0022lat\u0022: null, \u0022lon\u0022: `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok seems I've resolved it

```
{{ human_data|safe }}
```

**or** using `mark_safe` in views

```
mark_safe(serializers.serialize('json', human_values, fields=('pk', 'fio', 'lat', 'lon')))
```